# how to force exit exec_command if not returning a response from server

Tags: python, paramiko

No returning when executing this specific command, and hence, the command is never returned!

ssh to a server and sending some commands to it

```
class Ssh:
    def __init__( self, instance, ipaddress, username, password, type_ ):
       self.type_ = type_
       self.password = password
       self.username = username
       self.instance = instance
       self.client = SSHClient()
       self.ipaddress = ipaddress
       self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy( AutoAddPolicy() )
       self.client.connect( self.ipaddress, username = self.username, password = self.password )
    def std( self, message ):
      _in, out, err = self.client.exec_command( message, timeout = 10)
       exitcode = out.channel.recv_exit_status()
       stdout = ''.join( out.read() )
       stderr = ''.join( err.read() )
       return stdout, stderr, exitcode
```

server = Ssh( 1, '2.2.2.2', 'username', 'password', 'server')
server.std('rtm realign')

Comment: So where does your code hang actually? In `exec_command`, `recv_exit_status` or `read`?

Comment: at "exec_command"